# How to remove few tags contained between two different tags?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, mathml

Suppose I have something of the form:

```
`<semantics>
 ## from here
  <apply>
    <apply>
      <vector>
      </vector>
    </apply>
  </apply>
## to here
<annotation-xml>
   <apply>
   </apply>
</annotation-xml>
</semantics>`
```

After removing required tags I should get something of the form:

```
`<semantics>
    <annotation-xml>
       <apply>
       </apply>
    </annotation-xml>
    </semantics>`
```

I want to write a pattern to remove what all content is there between `<semantics>` and `<annotation-xml>` tags. How can I write a regex pattern or is there any better way of doing this?